# Put Paragraph tag for email send body

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I am getting error while putting paragraph tag for emailbody as below. Can someone suggest the wayout here?

```
mail.setHtmlBody(<p style="font-family:Calibri"> body</p>);
```

Error:

> Error: expecting a right parentheses, found '<'

Code snippet for body string:

```
String body = 'Dear ' + OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__r.Name + ', ';
       body += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
       body += '<br>New ABS Incidents have been generated in iREP. Please review these incidents with your DM or Applicable Manager. There is no other action for you to complete in iREP.';
       body += '<br>To view your open incidents:<br>';
       body += '•       Log into the iREP app on your iPad and select “Compliance Incidents”<br>';
       body += '•       Select the “Open Incidents” View in the Compliance Incidents Home Page.<br>';
       body += '•       Click the Incident ID to view your incidents If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.<br>';
mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri"> body </p>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code to as below.

```
mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri">'+body+'</p>' );
```

I have run this below code in developer console it is working fine. Hope this helps

```
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'xxx.xxx@xxx.com','xxx.xxx@xxx.com'}; 
   mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
   mail.setReplyTo('xxx.xxx@xxx.com');
   mail.setSenderDisplayName('My Name');
   mail.setSubject('Testing email through apex');
   mail.setBccSender(false);
   mail.setUseSignature(false);
   String body = 'Dear ' + 'User Name' + ', ';
       body += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
       body += '<br>New ABS Incidents have been generated in iREP. Please review these incidents with your DM or Applicable Manager. There is no other action for you to complete in iREP.';
       body += '<br>To view your open incidents:<br>';
       body += '•       Log into the iREP app on your iPad and select “Compliance Incidents”<br>';
       body += '•       Select the “Open Incidents” View in the Compliance Incidents Home Page.<br>';
       body += '•       Click the Incident ID to view your incidents If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.<br>';
   mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri">'+body+'</p>' );
   Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the input for the `setHtmlBody()` function needs to be of type String. You can make your html markup into a string by adding apostrophes:

```
mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri"> body</p>');
```

---

Since you don't want to include the word "body" in your email, but rather want the content of the `body` variable, you could make each of the surrounding tags into strings and perform concatenation with the `+` operator:

```
mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri">' + body + '</p>');
```

Comment: I tried that already . Getting only string name 'body' in email.

Comment: Is the font not getting set to Calibri?

Comment: Please find the image attached. It might be calibri but body value not coming

Comment: Well, have you tried formatting it in a way that will be obvious?

Comment: @SFDC_Learner I can't be 100% sure about the font from just that picture, but it looks like Calibri to me.

Comment: @martin But body is a string. I need it's value in email. How can I do that? Can you please let me know?

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Also sometimes the markup will get changed. In one instance I've noticed that setting a `style="font-family:Calibri"` attribute in a tag will get changed into a set of `<font face="Calibri">` tags.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner You just have to add the apostrophes around the content `'body'`and escape the apostrophes in the middle of the string `'It\'s me'`

Comment: @SFDC_Learner by the way, html tags will not be shown as text, so in the email, unless you look at the html markup of the document, you will not actually see the`<p style="font-family:Calibri">` and `</p>`.

Comment: @martin. I have updated my body string and mail send statements. Can you please look into that. Putting 'body' is getting errored out in paragraph tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mail.setHtmlBody('&lt;p style="font-family:Calibri"&gt; body&lt;/p&gt;');
```

Can't guarantee anything but worth a try.

Comment: I'm not sure if you noticed the edit, but it turns out `body` is the name of a string variable, and he didn't want the word "body" in the email.

Comment: @martin I get your point, but how to explain the error

Comment: @martin. I received this in mailbody now. "<p style="font-family:Calibri"> body</p> "

Answer (score 2):

Replace: `mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri"> body </p>');`

with: `mail.setHtmlBody('<p style="font-family:Calibri">'+ body +'</p>');`

`body` is a variable here. Hence, add it to the static string.